# value set for modal don't display when it is set through ajax success function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have a `table` that displays group name,etc and a `modal` that displays list of members.  When I click a particular group name, the modal shows up.. I set values for modal inside the success function of ajax but it doesn't display anything.. I also tried to do `alert(response)` inside the success function of ajax but the alert didn't show up.

here's my code:
for HTML table:

```
<div class="row table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed" id="r_data"> 
    <thead class="header">
      <tr class="well">
        <th style="font-size: 14px;">
            Group Name
        </th>
        <th style="font-size: 14px;">
            Leader's Name
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <?php if($result != NULL){?>
        <?php foreach($result as $row){?>
        <tr>
            <td data-toggle="modal" href="#viewMember" data-id="<?php echo $row->reservedID;?>">
                <?php echo $row->groupName;?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php echo $row->l_name.", ".$row->f_name." ".$row->m_name;?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php }?>
      <?php }?>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

here's the modal:

```
<div class="container" >
   <div class="row">
    <div class="modal fade" id="viewMember" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-md">
            <div class="modal-content"><!--CONTENT-->
                <div class="form-horizontal"><!--Horizontal-->
                    <div class="modal-header"><!--HEADER-->
                        <button class="btn btn-primary close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                        <h4 id="header"></h4> 
                    </div><!--END of HEADER-->
                    <div class="modal-body"><!--BODY-->
                        <div class="welll">
                          <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed table-responsive" id="records_table">
                            <thead class="header">
                                <tr class="well">
                                  <th>
                                    Member's Name
                                  </th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>

                            </tbody>
                          </table>
                        </div>
                    </div><!--End of BODY-->
                </div><!--END of Horizontal-->
            </div><!--END of CONTENT-->
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.viewMember').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
    var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
    var id = button.data('id')
    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo base_url('admin/group/getMember')?>",
        type: 'POST',
        data: { 'groupID': id},
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function(result){
            //alert("hi");
            $('.modal-body #header').text(result[0].fname);
        }

    });
});
```

controller:

```
public function getMember(){
    $data = array();
    $id = $_REQUEST['groupID'];
    $this->load->model('group_model');
    $data = $this->group_model->getAllMember($id);

    echo json_encode($data); 
}
```

Comment: instead of alert, can you console.log(result); and see response you got

Comment: i dont see any element with `hdrmsg` id. you can `console.log(result[0].fname)` in success.

Comment: @karanthakkar, I already edited it in my program but still id didn't show anything..

Comment: @NorlihazmeyGhazali, I tried `console.log(result)` and `console.log(result[0].fname)`  too  ,  but still it didn't show anything..

Comment: what this?? $_REQUEST['reserveID'];. Found this at your controller. Is it suppose to be received from ajax request right? And what you did send is data: { 'groupID': id}.

Comment: @NorlihazmeyGhazali..it's `groupID` rather...I used `$_REQUEST['groupID'];` and even tried `$_POST['groupID'];` to received the groupID so that I can use it for querying..

Comment: @NorlihazmeyGhazali, thanks, I can now show the value of `result[0].fname` in an alert.. but when I tried to set the value in modal like this: `$('.modal-header #header').text(result[0].fname);` it doesn't show anything..

Comment: Try change to $('.modal-header #header').html(result[0].fname); If this code did't work, try to console.log($('.modal-header #header').length); With this, you can see either your jquery selection is working or not. If work, you will get the number of existed element. If 0 is returned, your selector has a problem. Sometime, the selection will lead into problem.

Comment: Then the problem is, i did't see your html element that matched with this code `$('.modal-body #header')`, and of course there is no existed element that matched with this. Where you want to display output in your html. Can you show me where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, i did't see your html element that matched with this code `$('.modal-body #header')`. SO right now, i'm confuses with your question in term of displaying the output. I'm assume you want to display in header `<h4 id="header"></h4>`. If yes, then change your jquery code inside success block as following:

```
$('.modal-header').find('#header').html(result[0].fname);
```

It easy to make jquery selection, if you show where you want to display the output.